# Отступ от краев, что бы не задевал картину(не сузился при отступе). Отступ на весь сайт, что бы текст и т.д находились по середине

Tags: html, css, отступы

Более менее видно тут: https://prnt.sc/r9h9z1 <--
фото с макета, 
моё творение: https://prnt.sc/r9hc0s

Я пробовал просто использовать padding и margin, но они тупо сужают картину к середине(бока остаются белыми.

```
     <div class="start">
            <nav class="top-menu">
            <a class="navbar-logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                <ul class="menu-main">
                    <li><a href="asentus.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="introduction">
                <h1>HI-TECH DESIGN</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet consectetur adipiscing dolore magna aliqua <br/> enim minim estudiat veniam siad venumus dolore</p>    
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: хм, нет, это просто отступ.

Comment: а можно.. по подробнее?

Comment: вопрос еще открыт, помогите :с

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, суть вопроса. Вы просто хотите сделать отступ по краям?

Comment: не совсем ясно что именно необходимо сделать. Опишите вашу проблему по подробнее

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вот

```css
.center{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;

    padding: 0px 380px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="content">
            Контент
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```